# LeadingMarginSpan not indented correctly for multilevel/nested bullets

Tags: android, spannable, bulletedlist

I create a custom `BulletSpan` by extending `LeadingMarginSpan` to draw a custom bulleted items in a `TextView`. The documentation of `LeadingMarginSpan` says it can be nested (i.e. multilevel bullets):

> There can be multiple leading margin spans on a single paragraph; they
>   will be rendered in order, each adding its margin to the ones before it.

The `LeadingMarginSpan` class has this method:

```
public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,
                              int top, int baseline, int bottom,
                              CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                              boolean first, Layout l);
```

I don't know whether the implementation of the method should calculate the indentation itself or it has been indented. There's different behaviour across devices. For example, in **API level 21** it's called with `x` always 0, in **API level 23** it's called with different `x` for different level.

So, what is the correct way to implement this method?

Current implementation is much like the original `BulletSpan`:

```
    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,
                                  int top, int baseline, int bottom,
                                  CharSequence text, int start, int end,
                                  boolean first, Layout l) {
        if (((Spanned) text).getSpanStart(this) == start) {
            ...
            if (c.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
                ...
                c.translate(x + dir * mBulletRadius,
                        (top + bottom) / 2.0f);
                ...
            } else {
                c.drawCircle(x + dir * mBulletRadius,
                        (top + bottom) / 2.0f, mBulletRadius, p);
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Behaviour in **API level 21**:

```
o  Level 1
o     Level 2
o        Level 3
o        Level 3
o     Level 2
```

Behaviour in **API level 23**:

```
o  Level 1
   o  Level 2
      o  Level 3
      o  Level 3
   o  Level 2
```

*Thanks in advance*